# AU fanfic where Harry's voice is the Imperious and Tom is an empath

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a story where Tom and Harry find themselves in a universe in which each person has an ability that is a spell in the Harry Potter universe. Harry was the Imperious, Tom was an empath, Bellatrix had the Cruciatus curse, Minerva was the bodybind (i think). Harry and Tom avoided the Order but ended up at Hogwarts before I lost track of the fic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fic is [before they convinced you life is war](https://archiveofourown.org/works/17541269) by [EclipseWing](https://archiveofourown.org/users/EclipseWing/pseuds/EclipseWing)

Summary:
Harry's got the Imperius Curse tripping off his tongue and Tom's suddenly acutely aware of other people's emotions.

> Harry screams. And screams and screams and--
> The hurt is gone so suddenly he gasps at the loss of it. It feels like he had been born from the pain, that it was all he knows and the world comes back to him in bits and pieces. He's on the ground, sweaty and dishevelled and his throat is raw.
> Bellatrix leans over him, tone a croon as she reaches out, trailing one fingernail down Harry's jawline. "That's right," she simpers, "***You get the Imperius, I get the Cruciatus***." Harry shudders involuntary, nerve endings still on fire and her nail curls cruelly, digging into flesh and tearing through the skin sharply enough to draw blood.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. Yes, this was the fic I read. It's too bad to hear it was deleted. You certainly remember a lot more of the details than me! Hopefully, someone out there may be able to locate a copy. I didn't think anyone would be able to recognize the fic from the few details I could provide. Thanks again

Comment: I'll put out an ask on the hp fanfic subreddits and see if anyone has it saved up somewhere and I'll get back to you :]

Comment: @kat Found it! but credit goes to U/GildedSnow on Reddit who remembered the name. The problem was that it was tagged as a Mutants crossover instead of an X-men one.